# Creating A Table From Linked-objects Model

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following model which makes an element a parent of the element that follows it.
For example i get data from a server in an array of arrays like this:

```
net      Person       age
net      Person       height

net      Address      streetname

org      Company      name

org      Company      location

com      School       color

com      School       number
```

please kindly read the link below for the message yesterday and see the model classes and the structure. The question i asked in this link is not what i want now. I just want you to see the data model and the structure.

[Comparing Linked-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230164/comparing-linked-objects)

MY QUESTION NOW IS::

I want to create a table from the model but am finding it difficult to implement the Content and Label providers. So am asking how i can do it. 
Each  column will contain the children of the previous column and etc..

Thanks for your help.

I  tried this in the content provider but its not working:

```
public Object[] getElements(Object parentElement) {

              if(parentElement instanceof cPackage) {
         cPackage pack = (cPackage)parentElement;
         return pack.getChildren().toArray();
     }else if(parentElement instanceof cClass) {
         cClass klas = (cClass)parentElement;
         return klas.getChildren().toArray();
     }else if(parentElement instanceof cMethod) {
         cMethod met = (cMethod)parentElement;
         return met.getChildren().toArray();
     }
        return EMPTY_ARRAY;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If by "not working" you mean it's always returning `EMPTY_ARRAY`, then I suspect `parentElement` is not what you think it is. Try adding

```
System.out.println(parentElement.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

at the top of the method and seeing what you get.

On a side note, since `cPackage`, `cClass`, and `cMethod` all implement `getChildren()`, you don't actually need all those if statements -- just

```
if (parentElement instanceof Model) {
  return ((Model)parentElement).getChildren().toArray();
}
```

should do it. In fact, if you expect only `Model` subclasses to be passed in, you could leave out the `if` statement as well, though you might need to check for `null`.